# Do we ever find out what happens to former SeaQuest crew members?

Tags: seaquest

I know we see Benjamin Krieg again in Season 3 of [**SeaQuest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaQuest_DSV) (renamed SeaQuest 2032),

> and numerous characters such as Dr. Wendy Smith and Miguel Ortiz died on Hyperion in the battle of the Season 2 finale

but do we ever learn what happens to the rest of the cast, such as Dr. Kristin Westphalen or Katherine Hitchcock? Or supporting characters like Joshua Levin or Malcolm Lansdowne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There don't seem to be any references to the characters who were written out of the series in either the later shows, or any of the extended media that accompanied it.

The show spawned [two](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1214536.SeaQuest_DSV) tie-in [novels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441000428) (both set during the first season) and a [comicbook](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/seaquest-dsv/4050-20547/) adapatation (published during the second season, but set in the first season). Kristin Westphalen and Katherine Hitchcock appear extensively, but there's no in-universe reference to their whereabouts after the end of season one.